# Reducing the size of footnote marks in text

Tags: footnotes

I'm trying to change the size of footnote marker in the text, making it smaller, but no success.

Here is what I have in preamble: (slightly changes example from memoir class which I'm using)

```
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\tiny{\@thefnmark}}}}
```

but at compilation time all I get is

```
l.16 \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}
                                {\hbox{\textsuperscript{\tiny{\@thefnmark}}}}
?
```

and no effect.

What am I doing wrong? Is there other way to explicitly change the size of footnote marker from normal text size to smaller?

Comment: Maybe the [`superiors`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/superiors) package is something for you.

Comment: You need to enclose your redefinition in \makeatletter ... \makeatother

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I've been doing that all the way long, but nothing changes...

Comment: hmm... I'll post my document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You should indeed add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also there should be an error message in the line before `l.16 \re...`.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me, both for memoir and article class.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\tiny{\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example works perfectly. Though in my case it does not even when relevenat part is copypasted from your code... Guess in my case I need to disable certain packages/options and search for clash. But nevertheless it is weird.. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hello once again. Well everything boiled down to XeTeX, unfortunately, xunicode was the reason somehow. As soon as I switched back to pdflatex, the abovementioned code worked perfectly...